# Unmet dependencies when installing wine 5 or higher in Zorin OS 15.3

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, wine, bionic

I'm new at Linux and i need to upgrade to the latest of wine, but i got errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-staging : Depends: wine-staging (= 6.6~groovy-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried it before at
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-wine-on-ubuntu-18-04/

I did many steps:

1. OS

```
~$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Zorin
Description:    Zorin OS 15.3
Release:    15
Codename:   bionic
```

2. Verify 64-bit architecture.

```
~$ dpkg --print-architecture

amd64
```

3. See if 32-bit architecture is installed.

```
~$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures

i386
```

4. Get and install the repository key.

```
~$ wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key

‘winehq.key’ saved

~$ sudo apt-key add winehq.key

OK
```

5. Add the repository.

```
~$ sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'

Fetched 252 kB in 4s (70.6 kB/s)                    
Reading package lists... Done
```

6. Update the package database.

```
~$ sudo apt update

Fetched 252 kB in 4s (64.5 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

7. The next two commands download the libfaudio0 .deb packages into the local active directory.

```
~$ wget -nc https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/amd64/libfaudio0_19.07-0~bionic_amd64.deb

‘libfaudio0_19.07-0~bionic_amd64.deb’ saved

~$ wget -nc https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/i386/libfaudio0_19.07-0~bionic_i386.deb
libfaudio0_19.07-0~bionic_i386.deb’ saved
```

8. And these two commands do the installations.

```
~$ sudo apt install ./libfaudio0_19.07-0~bionic_amd64.deb

Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libfaudio0:i386
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libfaudio0
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 95.9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 544 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y

~$ sudo apt install ./libfaudio0_19.07-0~bionic_i386.deb

Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libfaudio0:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 99.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 300 kB of additional disk space will be used.
```

9. Install Wine.

```
~$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-staging : Depends: wine-staging (= 6.6~groovy-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

10. Try to update --fix-missing

```
~$ sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

Fetched 252 kB in 4s (70.5 kB/s)                                 
Reading package lists... Done
```

14. Install wine.

```
~$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-staging : Depends: wine-staging (= 6.6~groovy-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

15. Try to update & upgrade

```
~$ sudo apt update
~$ sudo apt upgrade

2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 289 kB of archives.
After this operation, 244 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport/ubuntu bionic/main i386 libfaudio0 i386 20.10-bionic~1ppa1 [150 kB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libfaudio0 amd64 20.10-bionic~1ppa1 [139 kB]
```

16. Install wine.

```
~$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-staging : Depends: wine-staging (= 6.6~groovy-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I don't know how to solve it, i tried with different `Codename:` like groovy and others but still same.